# Use RestTemplate in a static util method and concurrency access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, concurrency

I am having a util class as below, which has a static method to do rest invocation which is calling from many beans in the spring boot application. I only have logger as a instance variable in the Util class.

```
public class Util{

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Util.class);

public static String post(RestTemplate restTemplate){
   restTemplate.exchange();
}

}
```

I would like to get clarify below points.

1. Even I dont have a instance variable relate to RestTemplate in my util class, I notice with in RestTemplate class it has inner classes and maintain instance variables with in it. Would that be a issue when multiple users concurrently access the post method.
2. Is it ok to use org.slf4j.Logger as a instance variable here? Do I need to pass LOGGER as a method local parameter as well?

Comment: First thing, nothing to do with logger here. You can use Lombok for your logging purpose. I'm sure you will love Lombo library. Can you please show how you are calling this method post(RestTemplate restTemplate)...

Comment: through other beans as normal static method invoke

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1**

Every time a third-party API is called via RestTemplate it will create new Httpconnection and will close it once it is done. You can create RestTemplate's own connection pool using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory like so:

```
new org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory())
```

So it should not create any problems if the connections are new with each method call. Check this answer of mine here -- [How does resttemplate.exchange() execute on a different thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321329/how-does-resttemplate-exchange-execute-on-a-different-thread/55323106#55323106)

**Part 2**

Having a static variables in a util class with static methods only is fine. Having said that, Adding --

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Util.class);
```

-- in each of the classes seems to more of a boilerplate code which can be avoided if you use Lombok's `@Slf4j` annotation like so --

```
@Slf4j
 public class LogExample {
 }
```

This will generate somethig like this:

```
public class LogExample {
     private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);
 }
```

Comment: You can create RestTemplate's own connection pool using HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory -> Even with out create this there wont be an issue knw

Comment: @Harshana Right, that is an additional note if you would like to implement.